# Triangulate xyz Data Points

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, delaunay

Given a set of three 1D numpy vectors representing the `x`, `y`, and `z` coordinates of points on a surface, how would one convert these into a `meshgrid` to pass to `scipy.spatial.Delaunay` to create a triangulated mesh of the surface?

The documentation online shows examples of triangulating theoretical surfaces that can be `(u,v)` parametrized, but I would like to know how to do this for data points corresponding to a scan or physical data. I am not looking for a solution using marching cubes.

I am simply looking for a way to create a mesh grid from raw data rather than a theoretical "uv-surface".

Thank you.

Comment: please link to relevant docs

Comment: Also, why not marching cubes, or, what do you want to use instead?